# generate project for existing repository

Tags: git, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

When creating new Vue projects I use the Vue CLI (terminal). I run `vue create projectName` and get a local repository (with git files) generated.

When I have existing projects e.g. on Github this repository would have the following path

```
https://github.com/user/projectname.git
```

For now I clone this empty repository, generate a new one with the Vue CLI and move all the files from the local repository to the Github repository. After that I can delete the local one.

Is there a way to generate a new project and push the required files directly to an existing repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your existing github repository to remotes for your local repo via executing this

`git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECT.git`

After it you can push existing commits to remote repo
`git push origin master`

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have a repository on a local drive. When I run 

`git remote add origin git@G:\my\path\to\the\repo.git` 

and after that

`git push origin master` 

I get the error message that the service `g` could not be found. How can I deal with local drives?

Comment: If you running `git remote add`, it is supposed to be a remote repository as argument of command,, not local. You need to go to directory with your local repo and run this command with path to the repo on the github/gitlab/bitbacket or whatever you need